# Black screen once Splash Screen for IOS7 is added / XCode 6, Asset Catalog in Universal App

Tags: ios, xcode, splash-screen

Im building a universal iPad / Iphone App - with Xcode 6.

I have problems with the splash screen using Asset catalog.

Everything is working fine, until I start adding splash screen images for IOS 7 and later - this suddenly causes the screen to just show black.

Test on iPhone 4S , 8.1 / device and simulator.

I double checked the sizes, played with naming conventions - although this shouldnt matter, re-created the asset catalog a few times, double checked that Launch Screen file has no contents - but nothing seems to help..

Comment: Does your app launch in landscape? There's a known bug.

Answer (score 0):

It is curious:

If you uncheck all device orientation in General settings of your app, **the launch screen it shows perfect**. After that if you select all device orientations still works. But when i selected only landscape orientation doesn't work the launch screen.

In iPad works fine. The iPhone it shows black screen

**UPDATE:**

Finally works:
I had to add the files into my project with the correct names, and it's works, the launch screen with universal app in only landscape orientation.

- Default-Landscape~ipad.png (1024 x 768 px)
- Default-Landscape~ipad@2x.png (2048 × 1536 px)
- Default-568h@2x.png (640 × 1136 px)
- Default-568h@3x.png (1242 × 2208 px)
- Default@2x.png (640 × 960 px)

Hope help you